# Can I play a movie with a transparent background on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, movie

I'd like to supply my own background to a movie playing on the iPhone, for example a single-color background, a picture, the images from the camera.

Is it possible to play a movie with a transparent background on the iPhone, and if yes, how?

Comment: Will [this](http://www.sdkboy.com/?p=105) help?